# Why does my array contain the same elements?

Tags: java, arrays, object, for-loop, arraylist

Java beginner here. I'm trying to add Result objects from an ArrayList to an Array (to be sorted later). I know ArrayLists probably would work better but I'm required to use at least one array in this assignment.

In my code, I have made a copy of an array that is an instance of the class Event and I'm trying to iterate through it and add the best results from different Participant objects. When I run this, merely the best result of the most recently added Participant gets added to the array (same object in all indexes). How do I add the result from all of the objects in the list?

```
public void createBestResultArray(Event e) {        
    resultArray = Arrays.copyOf(resultArray,e.getParticipantAmount());

    for(Participant p1 : participantsInEvent){
          for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length ; i++){
             resultArray[i] = p1.getBestResult(e);
          } 
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(resultArray));
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to analyze if you could paste the code for `Event` class. and what is `participantsInEvent` variable? _the best result of the most recently added Participant gets added to the array_ you mean the entire array contains just one element?

Comment: @CKing Thank you for your answer! My problem is now solved. And thanks for the information, I'm new to Stack Overflow so I don't know much about how it works around here yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your for-loop. Assuming that `participantsInEvent` is a `List`, change your loop as follows :

```
for(int i=0;i<participantsInEvent.size();i++) {
    resultArray[i] = participantsInEvent.get(i).getBestResult(e) ;
}
```

The first for-loop in your question takes a participant from `participantsInEvent`. The second for loop then copies that participants best result to all index positions in the `resultArray`. This process is repeated for each participant. You are naturally left with the `resultArray` containing the best result for the last participant that was present in the `participantsInEvent` collection.